# произвольные числа js

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="form-exchange-row">
    <div class="form-exchange-col">
        Укажите комментарий к платежу
    </div>
    <div class="form-exchange-col">
        <span data-field="message"></span>
    </div>
```

в html имеется такой вот код!

есть js файл к которому идет обращение с помощью этого
значения `<span data-field="message"></span>`
в js имеется такой код

```
hide_all_windows();
var confirm_el = get_active_direction().find("[data-event='confirm_exchange']");
confirm_el.show().addClass('active');  
confirm_el.find("span[data-field='message']").html('ololo');
```

требуется генерация произвольного числа вместо "ololo"
в js совсем не шарю помогите как сделать генерацию чисел от 0 до 9

Comment: `int randomInt(){return 4;}` =) Используйте [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: не совсем понял, растолкуйте ?

Comment: Первая половина - [мем с xkcd](https://xkcd.com/221/), шутка. Вторая половина - ссылка на функцию, которая вам нужна

Comment: про функццию я знаю, я не могу ей воспользоватся из за незнание языка.
подскажите куда вставить этот код, что бы заработала все что я написал выше?

Comment: Чем не устраивает ответ ниже?

Comment: как совместить код который написал я и код предоставленный ниже?

Comment: Заменить `'ololo'` на `Math.random()*10|0` ?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> .html('ololo');
> ```

```
.html(Math.random() * 10 | 0);
```